# Estimating Exponential Decay Base

Tags: exponential-smoothing, weighted-mean

Suppose I have time series of noisy observations $\hat{Y_t}$, with the true underlying but not observable $Y_t$ ~ $N(\hat{Y_t},\sigma)$.

I want to estimate $Y_t$ with the basic model

$Y = mean(\hat{Y}_{0}...\hat{Y}_{t-1})$.

So far so good, now I want to add the fact, that the underlying $Y$ changes gradually over time, meaning $Y_t$ is slightly different from $Y_{t-1}$. So more recent observations should be weighted more heavily in the mean estimation. My new model is

$Y = wmean(w_0\hat{Y}_{0}...w_{t-1}\hat{Y}_{t-1})$ $\quad$ with $w_{t_0}= x^{distance(t,t_0)}$ $\quad$  ,$x\in(0,1)$.

So with $x$ approaching $1$ the decay would get slower. Do you have any idea how to estimate $x$? Is the only way to do it via parameter tuning (nicer word for trying around) or is there a way to fit it optimally via some model?